# Whats wrong with this yaml

Tags: yaml

It says YAML is invalid at this particular line Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
What am I missing

```
http:
  - request:
      path: /
      method: GET
    response: 
      headers:
        Server: Apache
        Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 15:54:09 GMT
        Etag: "19bbb-5beaee46ce7fa"
        Accept-Ranges: bytes
        Content-Length: 105403
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        Set-Cookie: HttpOnly;Secure;
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Content-Type: text/html
      file: 0.html
      status: 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is a special character.
Make it `"*"`